# How to view the query sent by pymongo to database?

Tags: pymongo

I have a query that is being built and sent to mongo using pymongo

```
result = list(collection.aggregate(sent_query))
```

The problem is that during debug I cannot view/copy the full query that is being dispatched to mongodb. I can see the parts of the query in an *sent_query* array, but I can't copy them as a one single query.

Using the *explain()* command is not good. I need a **real** output that will be in json/string format that I can copy and use in other tools to run the query,

Comment: _"I can see the parts of the query in an sent_query array, but I can't copy them as a one single query."_  Would you elaborate?  What prevents you from seeing the value assigned to `sent_query`?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = collection.aggregate(sent_query)
explaination = result.explain()
print(explaination)
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get the following error: AttributeError("'CommandCursor' object has no attribute 'explain'")

Comment: That explain command is not good. I need a real output that will be in json/string format that I can copy and use in other tools to run the query,